# How to display a Map object on a JSP from a Spring controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have to retrieve a `Map` from the controller and display the details as a table on a JSP.  The map returned from the controller is a `Map <String, List>.`  How do I do this?

Comment: make an effort to implement then come back with your code/issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as simple as you do in java.
I recommend you install [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-137889.html) jar file and use [taglibs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) in your file. Then use the `<c: forEach>` tag to iterate through the map and print them.

In you case,

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<table>
   <c:forEach items="${map}" var="mapElement">
      <tr>
           <td>${mapElement.key}</td>
           <c:forEach items="${mapElement.value}" var="listElement" >
              <td>${listElement}</td>
           </c:forEach>
      </tr>
   </c:forEach>
<table>
```